# Update rows using data within the same table SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table which looks like this

messageId | conversationId | campusA | campusB

```
1              1        campusA
2              1
3              1
4              1
5              2
6              2
7              2                   campusB
```

As we can see multiple messages are linked to the same conversationId and we have campus information for some of the records. Using this information I want to update remaining empty rows that are linked to the same conversationId. For example, I can see campusA is linked to conversationId 1. Using this information, I want to update the remaining 3 rows that have the same conversationId as the first record.

I was having trouble figuring this out and was wondering what would be the most efficient way to go around this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the update and correlated sub query as follows:

```
Update your_table t
  Set t.campusa = (select max(tt.campusa) from your_table tt 
                    Where t.conversarion = tt.conversation)
Where t.campusa is null
  And exists (select 1 from your_table tt
               Where t.conversarion = tt.conversation and tt.campusa is not null)
```